Emulating clicks in the iPhone Mirroring app
I'm trying to archive a couple hundred chats from an iOS-only app using iPhone Mirroring, since it's a pain doing it directly from the iPhone (you need to swipe and clink a bunch of times to archive every chat).
However, when using trying to use Keyboard Mastero and BetterTouchTool, I noticed that you can't emulate left clicks on the iPhone mirroring window.
I confirmed this in BetterTouchTool by assigning a keyboard button to a left-click. This worked in the Finder, but didn't work in iPhone Mirroring.
It might be that Apple is trying to "protect" the iPhone Mirroring window from outside emulation.  Is there any way workaround to allow clicks to take place?
